# Includegraphics: set image opacity

Tags: graphics, pdf, transparency

I'd like to insert a PDF, but make it "lighter" by setting the opacity to 10% ("background watermark"). How to do that? A solution that works with texlive 2011 would be great.

I use pdflatex and includegraphics to insert the image.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at PGF/Tikz http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf (search Referencing the Current Page Node - Absolute Positioning)

Comment: I hope there is a solution without loading the whole `tikz-pgf` bundle into my tiny document...

Comment: @topskip Certainly possible, all you have to do is use TikZ for a demo, `\tracingall` the resulting output and see what specials to use :-)

Comment: @JosephWright I guess my harddrive is too small for the resulting log file :)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could use the `transparent` package to set the opacity of your background image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{
    \put(0,0){
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
            {\transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{drawing}}%
            \vfill
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

In case the transparency doesn't work with your image for some reason, you could instead put a semi-transparent white box over your image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{
    \put(0,0){
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{drawing}%
            \vfill
        }
    }
    \put(0,0){%
        \transparent{0.7}\textcolor{white}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: First tests show that this works for some images only. "My" image of course does not work ...

Comment: @topskip: Oh, that's interesting. Have you made sure to compile the document twice?

Comment: @topskip: Workaround: Put a semi-transparent white rectangle above the image but below the text. See my edit.

Comment: Sadly does not work with beamer

Comment: Probably obvious, but: larger values for transparent mean more transparent.

Comment: Undefined control sequence. Using Xelatex.
l.4   {\transparent

Comment: @Jay it works with beamer, but doesn't seem to work with XeLatex

Answer (score 1):

To use `transparent` with XeLaTeX, insert

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}
```

at the very beginning of the document (before `\documentclass`).

See [this issue](https://github.com/ho-tex/transparent/issues/6) for more details.