# How to insert an image with transparent background into PDF?

Tags: graphics, transparency

I set the background of my PDF reader to be light green in order to describe my question. I want to insert an image into the PDF using LaTeX and hope the inserted image become part of the PDF file. Just like this figure:

[image]

However, I used the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package and inserted one image (EPS figure) into the PDF. The result looks like this:

[image]

How can I insert an image into a PDF file in LaTeX like the first figure?

This is not `transparency`. It is a SVG problem.

Comment: So, what you in fact want is [tag:transparency].

Comment: Is that actually the second image? A screen capture of your TeX code?

Comment: See also package `transparent` from `oberdiek` bundle and this answer: [Includegraphics: set image opacity](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86501).

Comment: Hi, this is not 'transparent' problem. This image format is SVG. we can use inkscape to convert SVG to PDF and then include the pdf format image into the pdf.

Comment: Well, what you show here, is _undoubtedly_ a transparency problem. You must make sure this while conversion from SVG to PDF then.

Comment: @Speravir  Yes. While converting svg to pdf, I need to make sure the background to be transparent.