# Opacity Logo in beamer slide

Tags: beamer, pdftex, include

Hi i have the following Beamer slide and i want to make the logo in the bottom right corner have an opacity on say 50 % ?

[image]
Here is my code

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, ]{beamer}
    \usepackage[danish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[]{algorithm}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinitialize{\textbf{\: \ initialization:}}
\algnewcommand\Initialize{\item[\algorithmicinitialize]}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{output:}}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\title[Dept. of Theoretical Statistics]{Particle Filtering for Sequential Markov Coalescent}
\author[Simon Schou Simonsen]{Simon Schou Simonsen}
\institute[]{\textit{In collaboration with: }\\\textit{Svend V. Nielsen and Asger Hobolth}}
\date{26. januar 2015}
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{segl.pdf}}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Program}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikz\node[opacity=.5,inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{segl.pdf}};`

Comment: Hi. I tried:
 \logo{\tikz\node[opacity=.1,inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{segl.pdf}};} 

but i had no success :(

Comment: Worked after exporting the PDF into PNG. Thank you

Comment: Weird.  It should also work for the PDF, except when the PDF is not an actual vector graphic but just a page with an embedded image.

Comment: For me it works with the PDF.  I downloaded the SEGL logo as SVG from [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9b/Aarhus_University_seal.svg) and converted it to PDF using `inkscape --export-pdf=segl.pdf Aarhus_University_seal.svg`.  Then, with [this sample document](http://hastebin.com/gifigibefa.tex) you can achieve [the desired effect](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O3rWY.png).

Comment: Try to overlay a semitransparent box: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86500/includegraphics-set-image-opacity

Comment: @HenriMenke Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter No, there has been no feedback from OP whether it worked or produced the desired effect.