how can I adjust the first includegraphics opacity?

xeLaTeX
i can't adjust the first background's opacity.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

i add a emptypage so i can skip the empty page with the dark background [\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\myemptypage{\null \thispagestyle{empty} \addtocounter{page}{-1}\newpage}]

@张晓风 Please add a short, but compilable test document to your question. Please add it in a code block and not as image.

More often than not it's useful or even mandatory to compile posted code, which demonstrates (!) the problem. As it is now we'd have to: 1) retpye your code, 2) add what's missing, 3) guess, which packages you may or may not have included ... and that's just the start. // However, if you follow these steps, you can post much better code for all of us: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 Thank you

Close- and Downvoters: This is a new user, give her or him time to react!

@Mensch Hi dearest. I think that the question is a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86500/includegraphics-set-image-opacity

@Sebastiano thank you ,your answer are very helpful, solve my question

Does this answer your question? Includegraphics: set image opacity

To change the opacity of the first page compared to the rest of the document, you can use the following setup:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}

% All page background setting
\backgroundsetup{%
  contents = \includegraphics{example-image},
  opacity = 0.05
}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{%
  % First page background setting
  \backgroundsetup{%
    contents = \includegraphics{example-image},
    opacity = 0.5
  }%
}

\begin{document}

% Your document...
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}

The idea is to set the background for all pages, and insert a page/shipout hook to update the background setup just for the first page.
